# The 'h1' tag is not changing its font size despite a value in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm facing a problem in changing the font size of the *h1* tag with CSS. I have set the size to *4rem*, but it doesn't change.

When I inspect the element in the dev-tools, `h1` is showing `font-size: 2.5rem;`:

[image: dev-tools showing initial CSS for h1 element]

And the h1 title ("Meet new and interesting...") font size looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of page with h1 title text 2.5rem]

But I want the h1 tag to be bigger, like this:

[image: Screenshot of page with h1 title text bigger, 4rem]

I got that screenshot by editing the `h1` CSS manually in dev-tools:

[image: dev-tools showing CSS for h1 element edited to be 4rem]

Why is my CSS for `h1` not showing up automatically?

**Code for CSS**

```css
#title {
    background-color: #ff4c68;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 4rem;
    Line-height: 1.5;
}

.container-fluid {
    padding: 3% 15%;
}
```

Comment: This should work, maybe you're override this from other place, or you are missing to include css file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Nenad Milosavljevic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70444739/h1-tag-not-changing-its-font-size-despite-value-in-css/70444755#70444755) is right, and I am just adding an explanation.

You might be having a CSS file in your HTML file which is overriding your internal CSS. To override that one, you need to put **!important** to your properties.

```css
h1 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 4rem !important;
    Line-height: 1.5;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
h1.hadeline {
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        font-size: 4rem !important;
        Line-height: 1.5;
    }
```

```html
<h1 class="hadeline">Meet your new and ....</h1>
```

Comment: Re *"hadeline"*: I think you mean *"[headline](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=hadeline)"*. In any case, where does it come from? Even more generally, an explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70444817/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 2):

While OP accepted Lokesh's answer about using `!important`, and others answered the same, *you should treat any time you want to use `!important` as a code smell that you might be not playing the CSS game correctly*, fighting against your other styling.

#### Simple specificity is better than `!important`

@Ashtrix is correct that increasing specificity is *better than* the `!important` sledgehammer — you can see in dev-tools that the matched CSS rule is single specificity `h1, .h1`, so even a single added class would make your rule be selected.

And the truth is, you are **not** looking for a standard `h1`, where all the h* sizes are proportionally bigger than the next one. So make a style `h1.huge` or something like that.

#### Not fighting against your styling library is even better

But even then, you'd be fighting against the styling library you're using!

I think you should pay attention to @Ashtrix's point about

> Seems like you have an external library Reboot that is taking over the styling.

The first search hit for "reboot css" leads you to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/reboot/, which mentions "responsive type-scaling". If you set `4rem` manually, you've lost any responsive scaling, that is to say: the library styles h1 smaller on phones than on desktop, which is a *good thing*.

So you need to ask the documentation, "How do I make a really big title font-size in this styling library?
And the answer is as simple as

1. Click on the [Typography](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/typography/) link in the docs
2. Skim the docs page to see its options for font size

There's 3 options that it presents to you:

- Increase the whole font size by changing `$font-size-base`. I do **not** think this is what you want.
- Use the [Display headings](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/typography/#display-headings) class, and adjust its styling if you want. This is targeting *exactly what you're looking for*:

> Traditional heading elements are designed to work best in the meat of your page content. When you need a heading to stand out, consider using a **display heading**

- Make your manual `h1.huge`, but make it *responsive*. There's a concrete example in the [Responsive Typography](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/typography/#responsive-typography) section

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `!important`:

```css
h1 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 4rem !important;
    Line-height: 1.5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have an external library, *Reboot*, that is taking over the styling. You need to increase the specificity of your tag.

```html
<h1 class="title">Meet your friends</h1>
```

```css
h1.title {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 4rem;
    Line-height: 1.5;
}
```

You can also use `!important`, but it is not considered a good practice, at least in simple use cases like this one where adding a class will suffice.